# Edit post count mismatch in profile

Tags: bug

There is a edit post count mismatch in `Profile` and `Editor Stats`.

In Editor Stats it's showing 89 edit suggestions approved

[image]

And in Profile it's showing 79 posts edited

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecWWp.png]

And I received sliver badge(`Strunk & White`) for 80 posts edit too.

Why this mismatch is coming? Is there any logic behind this?

Comment: Should you blame Cache? Like server side cache.

Comment: That’s 79 _posts_ edited, but 87 (not 89) _edit suggestions_ or _revisions_. Posts are not revisions.

Comment: No I am not comparing with revision count, I am comparing with suggestion count. Suggestion Count is showing 97 Suggestions where 88 edit suggestions approved, 16 edit suggestions rejected and 1 is in pending and in profile it's showing 79 posts edited.

Comment: Maybe you made multiple suggestions to the same post at some point? How edit count works is in the linked post

Comment: @VivekJain Approved suggestions _are_ revisions, and their counts are exactly the same for you, because they are exactly the same for you. However, posts edited is neither of them.

Comment: @user4642212 when you look into my profile there approved suggestions are 89 and revisions are 116.

Comment: @VivekJain Ah, yes, right, of course you can edit your own posts without approval, but still, those three things are all different metrics, in general. Do we need another post just asking for the distinction between the number of “approved edits” and the number of “posts edited” even though that other Q&A could simply be copy-pasted verbatim with “revision” replaced by “suggested edit”? It’s the same issue.